find proper value from column based on matching four columns in pair in excel
I have 5 columns in excel (code 1, code 2, kode1, kode4 and result1) and want to select proper value from "result1" based on matching columns (code1 and code 2) and also (kode1 and kode2). in fact if value in code 1 matches with value in code 2 and also value in kode1 matches with value in kode2 I can find correct value from column "result1" and write it in column "result2"
for better definition I added simple image and fill some proper values in column "result2"
this in my incorrect code
IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(D2,A:A),match(e2,b:b))

thank you very much

you are using match() twice in the index() function - once for the row and once for the column. You need to combine the matches.

Just FYI, you didn't fill in the last argument on your IFERROR.

You could use FILTER instead:
=FILTER($C$2:$C$11,($A$2:$A$11=D2)*($B$2:$B$11=E2),0)

Result:

For older versions which not support FILTER:
=INDEX($C$2:$C$11,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$11=D2)*($B$2:$B$11=E2),0))

Result:

Note: don't forget to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when entering array formula

HI, thank you. I use your code but unfortunately I received this error "that function isn't valid". I use excel 2013.

You should tag correct Excel version. Also, answer updated

Thank you. I used your code, unfortunately I got again error. I sent an image to you.

There is no image? Did you press ctrl+shift+enter to enter formula?

Sorry I didn't know how to attach image. I sent you my error. thanks



It looks like you didn't use ctrl+shift+enter when entering formula
